# nested CURSOR on information schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am doing nested cursor using information schema to SAVE my time to insert on all tables.

I am getting error 
[42P01] ERROR: relation "rec2" does not exist
Where: PL/pgSQL function test() line 22 at SQL statement

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Below is the code, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanking in advance.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
  rec1 RECORD;
  rec2 RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR rec1 IN
  SELECT
    C.table_name,
    C.column_name
  FROM "information_schema"."columns" AS C
  WHERE C.table_schema = 'prod1'
        AND C.table_name LIKE 'prd_tbl%'
        AND C.column_name <> 'id'
  ORDER BY C.table_name ASC
  LOOP

    FOR rec2 IN
    SELECT table_name
    FROM "information_schema"."tables"
    WHERE table_schema = 'ec2'
    ORDER BY table_name ASC
    LOOP

      SELECT rec2.*
      FROM rec2
      EXCEPT
      SELECT rec1.column_name.*
      FROM rec1;

    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Comment: You can't `select` from a cursor. But you don't need cursors at all for this. Just combine the two statements without a cursor.  Also `rec1.column_name.*` is invalid as well. `column_name` is a simple column, you can't apply `*` on a column that is a base type.

Comment: I need cursor so that i can do insert on each individual table one at a time. I haven't included INSERT TABLE statement because i want to make sure that first SELECT is working in CURSOR.